# Routing two network cards

Tags: networking, linux-networking, centos7

I got one server with two network cards.

NIC1 is 192.168.1.14 and can communicate with internal computers. 
NIC2 is 192.168.2.6 and can communicate with router and Internet.

From internal computers I can ping 192.168.1.14 and 192.168.2.6, but not ping 8.8.8.8 or any Internet site. Any idea?

Edit: I'm using CentOS 7, my default gateway is 192.168.2.2, and I stopped iptables but was unsucessful. 
Internal computers point destination 0.0.0.0 to gateway 192.168.1.14

Comment: What's is internal computer gateway? What's new server operating system?

Comment: What is the routing and NAT setup on the server?

Comment: `From internal computers I can ping 192.168.1.14 and 192.168.2.6, but not ping 8.8.8.8 or any Internet site. Any idea?` - What has this got to do with the server?

Comment: Have you enabled IP forwarding on the server: `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems like there is a NAT issue. I would follow this tutorial to properly NAT your internal network.

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html

Comment: Hi xR34, I read this tutirial but I got two questions: 1) Setting my iptables to accept everything would be the same (just for test), and 2) I didnt get the point, the eth0 is the network card for internal network?

Comment: _Setting my iptables to accept everything would be the same (just for test)_ - Not sure what you mean by that. _I didnt get the point, the eth0 is the network card for internal network?_ - No, the eth1 in the article is the internal network and the eth0 is the external network.

Comment: /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE     
Worked! Thank you!